# add multiple column condition in one where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

i have multiple columns from where i need to filter some data based on below conditions

Column A Like '%YT12-5%' and column B = '5656545'
Similarly i have multiple values for column A and B. Now i want to add both the conditions in one where clause so that the query performs fuzzy search the values from A and values from B together from the dataset to show the matching result

select * from table T
where "need the condition"

Comment: Just do it like you said `WHERE columnA LIKE '...' AND columnB = '...'`

Comment: What does *"Similarly i have multiple values for column A and B"* mean? You mean you have multiple conditions like `%YT12-5%` for A that pair with multiple conditions like `5656545` for `B`? You could use an OR: `WHERE (ColumnA Like '%YT12-5%' and columnB = '5656545') OR (ColumnA Like '%YT56-6%' and columnB = '1212123')`

Comment: A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would initially put your column B filter or filters if you have multiple. in the where first make sure you are picking up all of those.  Then apply your AND and then set your parenthesis with you like statements with OR's to pick up any of those along with your = to ColumnB

```
SELECT
*
FROM
T1
WHERE
(ColumnB = '' OR ColumnB = '')
AND (ColumnA LIKE '' OR ColumnA LIKE '')
```

Comment: If i have below data in the columns A and B

Table 1 
| Invoice | Customer |
| -------- | -------------- |
| DG7F-5   | 47836893 |
| H56-JKAG-5   | 47456758| 
| 76TT-JKN7-NJNJ | 58678489| 

Table 2
| Invoice | Customer | Amount|
| ---------------------- | -------------- |-------|
| DG7F-5457-3677| 47836893|33.66|
| H56-JKAG-5V55  | 47456758|77.78| 
| 76TT-JKN7-NJNJ | 58678489| 45.67| 
|DG7F-546G-44f7 |76768823| 56.99|
|H561-JKAG-55TG|47567658|34.77|